# JPA model/mapping for same table

Tags: jpa

How to create JPA model/mapping for name and surname relationship in the same Entity.

```
create table employee{
   empid number(25) primary key,
   name varchar2(100) not null unique,
   address varchar2(500) not null,
   surname varchar2(100) references employee(name) 
}
```

@JoinColumn and @OneToOne supports references of unique key in the same tale?

Comment: This is not even a problem, have you tried any tutorial to start with JPA, how-to's.

Comment: Looks weird having surname as a fk to name. What are you trying to achieve with this model? Sounds like an XY problem ;)

Comment: This is sample model and not original one.